# Problem with finding a partial derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $u(x, y)=f(\frac{x}{y})$ is a harmonic function,

a) solve the ODE satisﬁed by $f$.  ($U_{xx} +U_{yy}=0$)

b) Show that $∂u/∂r≡0$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ as usual.

I have solved part a as in picture but can’t get zero for part b.
Could anyone help me out?
[image]

Comment: Please prefer using Math-Jax to format your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates is $f(x/y)=f(\tan\theta)$, independent from $r$. But we can follow the hard way through the partial derivatives. First, the relation between derivatives and recprocals of derivatives doesn't hold: $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ has not the simple relation with his reciprocal as in one variable.

$x=r\cos\theta$ then $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta=\dfrac{x}{r}$

$y=r\sin\theta$ then $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\sin\theta=\dfrac{y}{r}$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}=$$

$$=\dfrac{f'}{y}\dfrac{x}{r}+\dfrac{-xf'}{y^2}\dfrac{y}{r}=0$$

Comment: Thanks, one more question. If we treat u as function of r and r as function of x and y we g

Comment: Not sure about what you are asking, anyway, there is no problem treating $f$ as function of $r$, but has to be function of $\theta$ too! as in the case posed.

Comment: I ment If we treat u as function of r and r as function of x and y we can’t get zero . Ie $$\frac{ \partial U}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.\frac {\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.\frac{x}{r}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}. \frac{y}{r}$$
if we find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ by for example summing of both Ux and Uy we can’t get zero .
what is wrong here??

Comment: The equations you have wrote are not true. E. g. the first must include the partial wrt $\theta$. You need too expressions for the polar coordinates as function of the cartesian ones. Think of matrices (made from the partials) transforming bases and components of vectors, all them pinned in a (generic) point in the plane